# Allow javascript button/action only after Stripe payment on static website

Tags: javascript, html, web, aws-lambda, stripe-payments

Is it possible to allow a certain Javascript action (clicking on a button to upload a picture or submit a form) only to visitors who paid using Stripe? (with Stripe checkout client only or Stripe payment links).

I am wondering if this can be achieved with only a static HTML+Javascript website or if some backend server needs to be implemented.

Ideally, when clicking on a button, there would be two possible outcomes:

- If the visitor has already paid --> The user can upload the picture or submit the form
- If the visitor has not paid: The user receive an alert message saying that they have to pay first

PS: maybe with some help of AWS Lambda...?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you check whether the visitor has paid. Assuming you will call some Stripe APIs on the backend, generally you would need to make an AJAX call to the backend and get back that result. Any backend would work, including AWS Lambda.